# Image isn't always inside DIV

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to wrap an `img` with a `div`. The problem is that the image loads left of the `div`. I currently have an image and `div` and know the image size prior to it being loaded. The `div` dimensions are set to the image's dimensions, but the image is loading left of the div. I've tried everything even adding a vertical-align to the image and the closest thing I came across was making the position of the `div` absolute which just loaded the div under the text which was right of the image. I probably can load the image in another `div` inside the original but that might harm SEO in my case.

**Position of the image**
[image]

**HTML**

```
<ul id="UL_1" class="ab-submenu">
    <li id="LI_2">
        <a class="ab-item" tabindex="-1" href="http://techdigy.com/wp-admin/profile.php" id="A_3"></a>
        <div class="avatar-holder" id="DIV_4">
            <img alt="" src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/95fef2e7b4a23f9cc0439619db1af0a6?s=64&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=G" class="avatar avatar-64 photo" height="64" width="64" id="IMG_5" />
        </div><span class="display-name" id="SPAN_6">Andre</span>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_7">
        <a class="ab-item" href="http://techdigy.com/wp-admin/profile.php" id="A_8">Edit My Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_9">
        <a class="ab-item" href="http://techdigy.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;_wpnonce=c7d2e50651" id="A_10">Log Out</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#UL_1 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0px 0px / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(204, 204, 204);
    color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    font: normal normal normal 13px/28px sans-serif;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 28px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: rgb(204, 204, 204) none 0px;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: rgb(68, 68, 68) 0px -1px 0px;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 99999;
}/*#UL_1*/

#LI_2 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0px 0px / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(204, 204, 204);
    color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    font: normal normal normal 13px/28px sans-serif;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 28px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 6px 16px 15px 88px;
    outline: rgb(204, 204, 204) none 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: rgb(68, 68, 68) 0px -1px 0px;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 99999;
}/*#LI_2*/

#A_3 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0px 0px / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(33, 117, 155);
    color: rgb(33, 117, 155);
    display: block;
    font: normal normal normal 13px/26px sans-serif;
    line-height: 26px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    min-width: 140px;
    outline: rgb(33, 117, 155) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 12px 0px 8px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    white-space: nowrap;
}/*#A_3*/

#DIV_4 {
    border: 0px none rgb(204, 204, 204);
    color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    font: normal normal normal 13px/28px sans-serif;
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 28px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(204, 204, 204) none 0px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: rgb(68, 68, 68) 0px -1px 0px;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 64px;
}/*#DIV_4*/

#IMG_5 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0px 0px / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(204, 204, 204);
    color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    display: block;
    font: normal normal normal 13px/28px sans-serif;
    height: 64px;
    left: -72px;
    line-height: 28px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(204, 204, 204) none 0px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: rgb(68, 68, 68) 0px -1px 0px;
    top: 4px;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 64px;
}/*#IMG_5*/

#SPAN_6 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0px 0px / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    display: block;
    font: normal normal normal 13px/28px sans-serif;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
    text-align: left;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    white-space: nowrap;
}/*#SPAN_6*/

#LI_7, #LI_9 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0px 0px / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(204, 204, 204);
    color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    font: normal normal normal 13px/28px sans-serif;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 28px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px 16px 0px 88px;
    outline: rgb(204, 204, 204) none 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: rgb(68, 68, 68) 0px -1px 0px;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 99999;
}/*#LI_7, #LI_9*/

#A_8, #A_10 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0px 0px / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(33, 117, 155);
    color: rgb(33, 117, 155);
    display: block;
    font: normal normal normal 13px/26px sans-serif;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    min-width: 140px;
    outline: rgb(33, 117, 155) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 12px 0px 8px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    white-space: nowrap;
}/*#A_8, #A_10*/
```

Comment: Please post some relevant HTML/CSS demonstrating this.

Comment: "I probably can load the image in another div inside the original but that might harm SEO in my case." - I can assure you, it won't

Comment: You can also use the developer or debugging tools of your browser to check the actual CSS (I think chrome calls it "computed"). The obvious cause could be a negative margin or absolute positioning, which are things that I assume you have avoided.

Comment: This is how it looks: http://jsfiddle.net/3ACCM/ Sorry it took me such a long time. the code kept on breaking.

Comment: Thanks Adam. If SEO isn't affected I might just do that, but wouldn't IE8 users be left out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct behavior, you are positioning the `img` absolutely `-72px` left and `4px` from the top.

```
#IMG_5 {
    position:absolute;
    left: -72px;
    top: 4px;
}
```

If you want the `img` to be inside the `div`, then remove the absolute positioning.

If you were trying to move the `div` apply this positioning to it as opposed to the `img`. In doing so, the `img` will also have the same position, as it is a child.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJ7t8/)

Comment: The CSS that's doing this is done by WordPress. Nevertheless, if I change the position to inherit or initial i think it will be places just as shown in your jsFiddle but it still is around 50px away from the left.

Comment: @AndreYonadam Or instead of overwritting it, simple change the code that is generated in the PHP.